# Unable to compile cordapp-example

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, corda

Am new to Corda and IntelliJ. While following instructions at https://docs.corda.net/head/getting-set-up.html#run-from-intellij am unable to compile the Corda example app. Gradle sync is giving me the following exception

Warning:***project ':kotlin-source': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration**
Details: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':kotlin-source:integrationTestCompileClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: **Could not find com.github.bft-smart:library:master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87.**
Required by:
    project :kotlin-source > net.corda:corda-node-driver:3.2-corda > net.corda:corda-test-utils:3.2-corda > net.corda:corda-node:3.2-corda*

Any guidance on what i am doing wrong here?

If i go to https://jitpack.io/com/github/bft-smart/library/master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87/library-master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87.jar It says *"Build failed. See the log at jitpack.io"*

As a further update the https://jitpack.io/com/github/bft-smart/library/master-v1.1-beta-g6215ec8-87/build.log shows the build failing since 30th August.

Any guidance on how i can force all of Corda to refer another version for the BFT-smart version? master-v1.1-beta-g34864da-135 ?

Comment: (update):- I added an issue with the Corda github at https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3884.

My current hack :- Just did a forced version with the following line in .....\cordapp-example\kotlin-source\build.gradle

compile "com.github.bft-smart:library:library-master-v1.1-beta-g93fe541-124"

Its working with this version.

Comment: So for some reason my account is not allowed to answer a question on SO :-)

This issue was fixed by the Corda-examples team. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/issues/154

Comment: Also got the following response via email

*"It seems that the binary expired on the third party binary repository, Jitpack. We are working to get it reinstated but another solution that is more long term is to add;
maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda' }
to your build.gradle's repositories blocks. This repository contains both Corda and any Corda dependencies we are hosting. You can still use jcenter/maven central for the main corda binaries if you put them higher in the repositories list."*

Answer (score 0):

This was raised as an issue [here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/issues/154) and fixed [here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/pull/155)

Take a look at this [post](https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/psa_for_corda_cordapp/25512136?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,25512136) on how to resolve